# How to delete Line feed on my lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I come to ask for help.
I have a document that it created automatically. This is the result of a SQL query.

an example of line with line feed. With word we see that

```
"2K45.10 NEW";"ARC CA 125 CONTROL";"4";"0";"8 640";
"2K45.23 NEW";"ARC CA 125 REAGENT 400 TESTS ";"4";"0";"103 777"
"2K45.28 NEW";"ARC CA 125 REAGENT 100 TEST ";"4";"0";"27 113"
"2K46.01";"ARC ANTI TG CALIBRATOR ";"4";"0";"11 626"
"2K46.10";"ARC ANTI TG CONTROL";"4";"0";"8 483"
"2K46.25";"ARC ANTI TG RGT 100 TEST ";"4";"0";"26 872"
```

If i open by Nopad++

```
"2K45.10 NEW";"ARC CA 125 CONTROL";"4";"0";"8 640";"BOITE";"";"TAXE 39% CD 38220000000"
"2K45.23 NEW";"ARC CA 125 REAGENT 400 TESTS 
";"4";"0";"103 777"
"2K45.28 NEW";"ARC CA 125 REAGENT 100 TEST 
";"4";"0";"27 113"
"2K46.01";"ARC ANTI TG CALIBRATOR 
";"4";"0";"11 626"
"2K46.10";"ARC ANTI TG CONTROL";"4";"0";"8 483"
"2K46.25";"ARC ANTI TG RGT 100 TEST 
";"4";"0";"26 872"
```

The problem is that in certain lines, there are Line feed and when I run my script, there or there of the line feed me here cut my line. Below is the script I use.

```
@echo off & cls

Set "$c=1"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
  if !$c!==1 (
    set $l=%%a
    set /a $c+=1
    ) else (
    echo !$l!%%a
    set "$c=1"
  )
))>sortie.txt
```

And the result is

```
"2K45.23 NEW";"ARC CA 125 REAGENT 400 TESTS ";"4";"0";"103 777" 
"2K45.28 NEW";"ARC CA 125 REAGENT 100 TEST ";"4";"0";"30 652";
"2K46.01"   ;"ARC ANTI TG CALIBRATOR ";"4";"0";"11 626"
"2K46.10"   ;"ARC ANTI TG CONTROL";"4";"0";"8 483" "2K46.25";"ARC ANTI TG RGT 100 TEST 
";"4";"0";"26 872";"2K47.01";"ARC ANTI TPO CALIBRATOR
```

I don't understand why, For lines without LF, there are more CRLF

Thank you for the help you bring me.

Comment: If you open the SQL query output text file in Notepad++ and click the Encoding menu, what is selected?  After you run your batch script fix and open again in Notepad++, is the encoding changed?

Comment: Does it display correctly if you use the command MORE sortie.txt

Comment: What is `word`? Is that the Microsoft Word editor? If so, the easy answer is to stop using Microsoft Word for plain-text files like this.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35165390.txt"

Set "$c=1"

for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("%filename1%") do (
  if !$c!==1 (
    set $l=%%a
    set /a $c+=1
    ) else (
    echo !$l!%%a
    set "$c=1"
  )
)

ECHO ==============

Set "$c="

for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("%filename1%") do (
 IF DEFINED $c (ECHO !line!%%a&SET "$c="
 ) ELSE (
  SET "line=%%a"
  SET "line=!line:"=_#_!"
  IF "!line:~-3!"=="_#_" (echo %%a) else (set "$c=1"&SET "line=%%a")
 )
)

GOTO :eof
```

The first part of this batch is your code with a couple of small changes to read the data from a file named to suit my system.

Given the data you show as the `notepad++` version, the result of running this code is:

```
"2K45.10 NEW";"ARC CA 125 CONTROL";"4";"0";"8 640";"BOITE";"";"TAXE 39% CD 38220000000""2K45.23 NEW";"ARC CA 125 REAGENT 400 TESTS 
";"4";"0";"103 777""2K45.28 NEW";"ARC CA 125 REAGENT 100 TEST 
";"4";"0";"27 113""2K46.01";"ARC ANTI TG CALIBRATOR 
";"4";"0";"11 626""2K46.10";"ARC ANTI TG CONTROL";"4";"0";"8 483"
"2K46.25";"ARC ANTI TG RGT 100 TEST ";"4";"0";"26 872"
==============
"2K45.10 NEW";"ARC CA 125 CONTROL";"4";"0";"8 640";"BOITE";"";"TAXE 39% CD 38220000000"
"2K45.23 NEW";"ARC CA 125 REAGENT 400 TESTS ";"4";"0";"103 777"
"2K45.28 NEW";"ARC CA 125 REAGENT 100 TEST ";"4";"0";"27 113"
"2K46.01";"ARC ANTI TG CALIBRATOR ";"4";"0";"11 626"
"2K46.10";"ARC ANTI TG CONTROL";"4";"0";"8 483"
"2K46.25";"ARC ANTI TG RGT 100 TEST ";"4";"0";"26 872"
```

Which means that the data would seem to contain characters that are interfering with the processing.

Note that your `word` version does not include `"BOITE";"";"TAXE 39% CD 38220000000"` for instance.

But my output from your code does not match your output from your code (and your output misses the entire `...BOITE...` line.)

So - somewhere we are getting `word` and `notepad++` interpreting the same data differently.

I use `editplus`, which allows me to see the actual hex-codes in the file. Perhaps if you could examine the file with a hex-editor, the true file contents would be revealed.